# $.getJSON got a 404 error with a wrong url and [object%20Object], how did it happen?

Tags: node.js, ember.js, express, getjson

I use grunt-contrib-connect to serve as my front end server(`http://127.0.0.1:8888`) and express as my backend server(`http://127.0.0.1:3000`). The front framework is Ember.And I did the cross domain visit by adding Access-Control-Allow-Origin and Access-Control-Allow-Methods to all the req. Now I call:

```
$.getJSON({
    url: http://127.0.0.1:3000/index?callback=?
});
```

And the /index cgi code is:

```
router.get('/index', function(req, res) {
    var cb = req.params.callback;
    res.send(cb({name:'test'}));
});
```

The browser's console printed an error:
GET `http://127.0.0.1:8888/[object%20Object]` 404(Not Found)
This wrong url is not my cgi url, how did it exist here?
What can I do to solve this issue?
Thank you

Comment: What kingpin said. Also, you wont be able to pass a function the way you intended

Answer (score 3):

`getJSON` takes a string, not a hash `$.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:3000/index?callback=foobar');`

Comment: Yes buddy, I mistook the params with &.ajax, thank you